# Cannot assign a value to final variable

Tags: java, android, http, final

Here's my code:

```
public String getGPA() {
        String gpa = null;
        final String responseBody1;
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                try {
                    HttpGet httpGet_gpa = new HttpGet("https://somedomain.com" + getRegId() + "&format=P");
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet_gpa);
                    responseBody1 = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                    // Ignore
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    // Ignore
                }
            }
        }).start();
        Document gpa_doc = Jsoup.parse(responseBody1);
        Element p = gpa_doc.select("p").first();
        gpa = p.text().replace("Your overall GPA (Grade Point Average) to date is:", "");
        return gpa;
    }
```

I'm getting this error: `cannot assign a value to final variable responseBody1`. What does this mean? I tried removing the final modifier but it tells me I need to make it final, but when I do i get that error. Any clues on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

That's the problem related to anonymous classes. Since Java's black magic creates a copy of the environment in which the class is instantiated to pass variables to the inner class, you must declare them as `final`. Changing `responseBody1` wouldn't change the original variable but a local reference to it (and since `String` is immutable you won't obtain what you think).

You should pass through a wrapper or a method of the outer class.

Answer (score 1):

If you create an anonymous class that implements an interface (such as `Runnable`), any local variables that it accesses must be `final`, and their values have to be determined at that point.  The anonymous class isn't allowed to change those variables in a way that the outer method could see the changes.  (This is a feature of Java; other languages allow outside local variables to be changed.)

I can't recommend a solution, because it looks to me like your method won't work anyway.  You create a new thread and use `start()` on it, and it looks like you're expecting this thread to modify `responseBody1`.  But your method then tries to use the value of `responseBody1`.  You cannot tell whether the thread has gotten to the point where it modifies `responseBody1`, since you don't do anything to wait for the thread or synchronize with it in any way.  Something else about the design will need to change.

However, a possible solution is to define a new class that contains a `String` member:

```
static class StringHolder {
    String responseBody1;
}
```

Then create a `new StringHolder` and assign a `final` local variable to this.  Although the reference to the `StringHolder` can't be changed, the `responseBody1` member can still be changed by the thread.

Answer (score 0):

The final attribute means that you pledge not to modify the variable. That's why you can't modify your variable.

If you are forced to use a final, it's super easy : just do like so

```
String newString = responseBody1;
```

And then modify newString as you will

edit:

Just realized that it's not what you want. You can use a function that you will call in your anonymous class

Update :

```
private static String responseBody1;

public String getGPA() {
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run()
        {
           fetchResponse();
        }
    }).start();
    Document gpa_doc = Jsoup.parse(responseBody1);
    Element p = gpa_doc.select("p").first();
    gpa = p.text().replace("Your overall GPA (Grade Point Average) to date is:", "");
    responseBody1 = null;
    return gpa;
}

public static void fetchResponse(){
try {
       HttpGet httpGet_gpa = new HttpGet("https://somedomain.com" + getRegId() + "&format=P");
       HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet_gpa);
       responseBody1 = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
    } catch (IOException ioe) {}
}
```

Now I'm not sure if it has to be a static function and a static responseBody1. But I'm guessing so.

Comment: What's the difference between `final` and `static` if you can't modify it? Also, I need to access `responseBody1` after it's loaded with some data by `EntityUtils.toString`, but I'm unable to access the data since I need to set the variable to `final` and once I set it to final I cannot load any data onto it and then read it from outside the thread

Comment: Static means that there is only going to be one instance of a variable in a class. That means that any object of this class will have access to the same variable. About responseBody1, I edited my answer. Just create a static function with your try catch in it, and call that function inside run()

Comment: @Gaktan What is this static function going to do?  If it returns the `String`, the `run()` method in the thread will have to assign something to the function result, and you haven't solved the problem.  Perhaps you should post a code example to demonstrate your solution.